# Difference between Content and LoadContentFrom

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

What is the different between Content and LoadContentFrom properties of Kendo UI's Window contorl.  I have two button in Home page.  Each button have separate window control to call corresponding partial view.  If i use content method, the customer index loaded initially, ie at the time of page load.  If i use LoadContentFrom, the DOM controls gets loaded when the window gets visible.

For example,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("CustomerWindow")
    .Title("Customer")
    .Content(@<text>
@Html.Partial("../Customer/Index")
</text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(736)
    .Visible(false)
)
```

and

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("CustomerWindow")
    .Title("Customer")       
        .LoadContentFrom("../Customer/Index")
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(736)
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
)
```

I think its lazy loading concept,  but I don't know the exact difference.

thanks
Santhosh

Answer (score 2):

The `LoadContentFrom` setting specifies an URL which the window will load using Ajax request. `Content` defines the static HTML content of the window.